# Guest Entries creating new entry instead of editing the current one

Tags: guest-entries, plugin-guestentries

I am using the GuestEntries (https://github.com/pixelandtonic/GuestEntries) Plugin to try to allow guests to update entries. I have it working to where a guest can come to the page and fill out the form but unfortunately it is creating a new entry rather than editing the existing one.

Answer (score 3):

I got it to work by adding the below at line 182 of GuestEntriesController.php

```
        $entry->id = craft()->request->getPost('entryId');
```

Then I added a hidden field with the current entries id in the template.

```
<input type="hidden" name="entryId" value="{{ entry.id }}">
```

I don't know if this is the best way to do it but it seems to be working. If this is going to cause issuees or there is a better way to do it let me know and I will swap my fix out with yours.